# In which kind of Journal should i publish my math applied based paper regarding a political problem?

Tags: publications, mathematics, paper-submission, politics

I'm currently working on a voting analysis paper, most of the theory is about, "math", i'm talking about linear algebra, programming, big data, and that specific knowledge area, however the paper is all oriented into  a specific problem regarding politics as it's entirely related to voting analysis and stablishing political networks based on it, so to which kind of journal would be better to send it in order to get published, one of applied math, or one of political science. i've check and it meets requirements of both journals.

Which are the advantages of publishing on one instead of the other?

Comment: I think this answer is relevant: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/42389/10529